# Getting starting with Android - which direction to go?

Tags: android

I'm a Java developer at heart. Just got Android based phone and curious if I can write some app for it. I know its late in the game, but why not. I guess a question to all those who write for Android. What is the approach? After some quick googling I found out that applications can be written in:
 - Java using android SDK
 - Flex from adobe offers
 - JavaFX seems they do that too
 - Or other commercial tools that promise my app will run on any mobile device

There seems to be a cesspool out there with all the marketing and quick money making schemes attached to mobile development.

In the end, whats the best way to start for seasoned Java developer?

Thanks.

Comment: Install the SDK, stick to Java, read the dev guide on d.android.com, that should get you started and you should be able to do already quite a few things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I use Eclipse IDE with the Android SDK. If you're used to Java - then stay with it.

A good starting point is to read about the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) as it is a very big part of how your app will function.

The second approach is to hit the [Tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial). I'm a hands-on person so learning by doing is prefered.

Answer (score 0):

Some helpfull links:

http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SVZ1P35xgNQ&feature=results_video&playnext=1&list=PL412E536D5FF8899D

http://commonsware.com/Android/Android-1_0-CC.pdf